# Resolve Uncaught ReferenceError: not defined(…)

Tags: php, ajax

hi am getting the error

> new_ Uncaught ReferenceError: get_class_sections is not defined(…)

in my onchange function for ajax, how do i resolve this, the resolutions have seen so far don't apply to me.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="state" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%;" data-validate="required" id="State" 
        data-message-required="State Required" onchange="return get_state_cities(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php 
            $notarray = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from('state');
            foreach($notarray as $row):
            ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $row['state'];?>"> <?php echo $row['state'];?> </option>
            <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

ajax function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function get_state_cities(state) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'func.php',
        data: { param1: state, action: city}
        success: function(response)
        {
            jQuery('#city_selector_holder').html(response);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `get_class_sections` is not mentioned in any of the code you've shared with us.

Answer (score -1):

For any one who gets into this same kind of trouble, your ajax function should look like this

```
script type="text/javascript">

function get_state_cities(state) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'func.php',
        data: {stat: state},
        success: function(data)
        {
            jQuery('#city_selector_holder').html(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Aside from being an insignificant edit of the code in the question, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem described (not that the code in the question did either).